# Is it possible to create a selector that accesses multiple branches of the state tree?

Tags: redux, react-redux, reselect

I am working on a Redux project with a bunch of reducers that are combined

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    reducer1,
    reducer2,
    ...
});
```

The reducers each update a branch of the store

```
sampleStore = {
    reducer1: {a1: 7, b1: 5, c1: 6, ...},
    reducer2: {a2: 3, b2: 2, c2: 9, ...},
    reducer3: {a3: 1, b3: 4, c3: 2, ...},
    ...
}
```

Now I am trying to add logic that requires access to both branches of the store without restructuring the entire project. For instance, I want a reducer with the ability to perform: `set c3 = f(a1, a2)`.

At the moment I am trying to use reselect but I am getting lost. In reducer1/selector.js I have

```
export const derivedVariableSelector = createSelector(
    a1Selector,
    a2Selector,
    (a1, a2) => a1 + a2
);
```

And I am trying to create a reducer

```
function setC3(state) {
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
        c3: state.c3 + derivedVariableSelector(state)
    });
}
```

However, when setC3 is called, derivedVariableSelector will never receive enough of the store to do its job. Either it will receive the branch containing a1 or the branch containing a2, but I don't know of a way to supply both. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is "No", so long as you're using `combineReducers` to combine all your reducers.

The longer answer is taken from the [redux documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/BeyondCombineReducers.html#beyond-combinereducers):

> The combineReducers utility included with Redux is very useful, but is
>   deliberately limited to handle a single common use case: updating a
>   state tree that is a plain Javascript object, by delegating the work
>   of updating each slice of state to a specific slice reducer. It does
>   not handle other use cases, such as a state tree made up of
>   Immutable.js Maps, trying to pass other portions of the state tree as
>   an additional argument to a slice reducer, or performing "ordering" of
>   slice reducer calls. It also does not care how a given slice reducer
>   does its work.
>
> The common question, then, is "How can I use combineReducers to handle
>   these other use cases?". The answer to that is simply: "you don't -
>   you probably need to use something else". Once you go past the core
>   use case for combineReducers, it's time to use more "custom" reducer
>   logic, whether it be specific logic for a one-off use case, or a
>   reusable function that could be widely shared.

On the same page of the docs are some suggestions for [how the create reducers that share more of the state](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/BeyondCombineReducers.html#sharing-data-between-slice-reducers) but it's going to be a bit more manual than `comibineReducers` is.

I haven't tried anything like this myself before, but following examples in the docs, something like this might work for you:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import reduceReducers from 'reduce-reducers'

const reducer1 = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        // handle actions
        default: 
            return state
    }
}

const reducer2 = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        // handle actions
        default: 
            return state
    }
}

const reducer3 = (state) => {
    return {
        ...state,
        // use the root state for the reducerC value
        reducerC: makeValue(state.reducer1, state.reducer2)
    }
}

const rootReducer = reduceReducers(combineReducers({reducer1, reducer2}), reducer3)
```

This uses the library [reduce-reducers](https://github.com/acdlite/reduce-reducers) to combine reducers in a different way.